# bash to test if command can run

Tags: bash, makefile

I have the following `makefile`:

```
SHELL += -eu
GREEN=$(shell echo -e "\033[0;32m")
RED=$(shell echo -e "\033[0;31m")

AWS=$(shell command aws --version 2> /dev/null)
all: prereqs
    @echo "${GREEN} ✓ Testing our local environment for dependencies."

prereqs:
    ifndef "${AWS}"
        $(error "${RED} AWS is not available please install aws-cli")
    endif
        "${AWS}"
```

How do I change it so that if there is dependancy missing to show a more appropriate error and continue with the check?

I tried:

```
prereqs:
    aws --version || $(error "${RED} AWS is not available please install aws-cli")
    @echo
```

But it does not seem to be working, what am I missing as `aws` exists!

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: This isn't bash, it's `sh`. Make doesn't use bash unless it's told to. Correct your tagging.

Comment: (that said, it's `sh` with some non-POSIX-compliant extensions -- `echo -e` isn't allowed to do anything other than print `-e` on output by [the letter of the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html); see in particularly the APPLICATION USAGE section showing how to use `printf '%b\n'` instead).

Comment: ...for a case in point (assuming that `/bin/sh` is provided by bash running in POSIX mode on your system), see how your makefile behaves if run after `export BASHOPTS=xpg_echo`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a couple of points of knowledge about how `make` works:-

- [The difference between recursively expanded and simply expanded variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html)
- [The syntax of `ifdef`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html)

Write this instead:

```
SHELL += -eu
GREEN=$(shell echo -e "\033[0;32m")
RED=$(shell echo -e "\033[0;31m")

AWS:=$(shell command aws --version 2> /dev/null)
all: prereqs
    @echo "${GREEN} ✓ Testing our local environment for dependencies."

prereqs:
ifndef AWS
$(error "${RED} AWS is not available please install aws-cli")
endif
    @echo "${AWS}"
```

and note the differences.

I also think an improvement would be:

```
SHELL += -eu
GREEN=$(shell echo -e "\033[0;32m")
RED=$(shell echo -e "\033[0;31m")

AWS:=$(shell command aws --version 2> /dev/null)
$(info ${GREEN} ✓ Testing our local environment for dependencies.)
all: prereqs

prereqs:
ifndef AWS
$(error "${RED} AWS is not available please install aws-cli")
endif
    @echo "${AWS}"
```

as well not leaving the user in a coloured shell.

Comment: *grumbles a bit about keeping the OP's non-POSIX-compliant `echo -e` usage, vs converting to `printf '%b' "\033[0;32m"` or such*

Comment: Also, leaving the ifndef in the context of the prereqs target is misleading: people might think it's only run when the prereqs target is run which is not true, it's run when the makefile is parsed.  I recommend putting it up just after the `info` and before the `all` target so it's more clear what actually happens.